# Хранение PHP-переменных в памяти

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, где можно почитать про память в PHP. Я не знаком с С, но меня интересуют следующее:

```
$pizza  = "кусок1 кусок2 кусок3 кусок4 кусок5 кусок6";
explode(" ", $pizza);
```

Мне интересно как выделяется память, где хранится массив, который возвращает `explode()` (именно без переменной), можно ли к нему обратится без переменной . Хочется знать больше деталей.

Comment: Хранятся в памяти. Где же ещё храниться. Но если Вы не присваиваете результат выполнения функции, то результат потеряется (а в некоторых случаях компилятор/интерпретатор может и совсем выбросить подобную строку).

Comment: Я считаю, что это и есть огромное отличие php от c/c++. PHP - это скриптовый язык. Грубо говоря скрипт. Он не хранит в процессорной памяти данные, в ячейках памяти, как это делает Си. Грубо говоря в нём чётко и последовательно следуют команды. Тут уж значение без переменной не подвесишь. Вывести его, или передать - с помощью того же `return` или `echo`, например, без проблем. А вот сохранить без переменной - нев...)))

Comment: результат `explode(" ", $pizza);` представляет собой массив, область памяти им занимаемая немедленно будет помечена на сборку мусора, как оно работает в php в деталях я не знаю, читайте исходники php они на C (придется познакомиться) ,

Comment: В куче все валяется, как и в любом другом слаботипизированном языке.

> можно ли к нему обратится без переменной

Я не уверен что в PHP вообще есть функции работы с памятью, но если и есть, вам все равно будет необходимо обогнать GC.